# Column Terminology

Tags: mysql, terminology

I'm a MySQL student here trying to learn the proper way to call things in the SQL language.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    width SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    height SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    content TEXT,
    date_added DATE NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In the above SQL, "id" is the column name, INT is the data type, but what are the following keywords known as: NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY, UNSIGNED.

Not asking what they do or how they work, just asking what they're known as in the SQL world, e.g., SMALLINT is known as a "data type."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `id` is the column name

True

> `INT` is the data type

False. Datatype is `INT UNSIGNED`.

> what are following known as?

`NOT NULL`, `AUTO_INCREMENT` - they are named "attributes". More precisely, they are "column attributes".

`PRIMARY KEY` - this is NOT a part of column definition, this is constraint (and according index) definition/specification.

All above is explained in [CREATE TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html#create-table-types-attributes) article.